# how are the html/.net controls identified in external js file?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

All I wanted to know is if all the aspx/html pages have controls with the same name and all of them are referred in a common js file, will that not lead any conflicts?

For example: `txtComment` and `txtDate` are two controls in `one.aspx` and they are referred in `one.js`. At the same time, these two controls are defined in `two.aspx` and are referred in `one.js`. Now how does the server know where to return after this script is executed.

Experts please throw some light on this. thank you

Comment: I have no idea what you mean?

Comment: let me explain. Can I use same control names in different aspx pages and reference them in one common js file? if so how does the server know which page requested execution?

Comment: I think I have given enough explanation, if you dont understand it please dont downvote

Comment: @hima: `.net` recognizes files correctly. I am not sure what is the problem you having? And also even if you gave the same name, those will get change at run time. Please have a look with firebug you will see names been applied to controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ASP.NET code essentially runs and produces HTML documents. Part of this generated HTML can include references to external JavaScript files, via the HTML `script` tag. Once the HTML page is fully formed on the server, and sent down to the client browser, the browser itself sees that JavaScript reference, and executes the JavaScript contained with it.

The JavaScript itself is not actually aware of your ASP.NET controls. Rather, it executes code that looks through the HTML document object model (the DOM), and attempts to find HTML elements. You'll see code like `var x = document.getElementById('thing');`, which basically tells the script to find an HTML object with an ID attribute of 'thing', and create a reference to it in a variable named 'x'. From there, you can manipulate the HTML element referenced by 'x' with the other methods that you get in JavaScript. You can destroy it, clone it, change its HTML contents, change its various HTML attributes, and much more.

Your page all works together seamlessly because you have entered into the JS file the correct ID's of the elements to manipulate. The JS file itself cannot truly be aware of the fact that they are actually ASP.NET controls that render as HTML on the server.

Comment: thank you for the beautiful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript executes in the context of the page it's included on with the `<script>` tag. It doesn't know or care about what actual page this is (you could include logic based on location I guess).

The fact both pages have controls it can reference is incidental. Try removing a control from one page and watch what happens.

Also, remember the JavaScript executes client side, so the server doesn't care where it returns.